# Angular 11 : circular dependency

Tags: angular, typescript, circular-dependency

**Here my error in Typescript :**

> Warning: Circular dependency detected:
> src\app\components\elements\modal\update-keyword-modal\update-keyword-modal.component.ts
> -> src\app\components\elements\validator\unique-keyword-name-validator.ts
> -> src\app\services\keyword\keyword.service.ts -> src\app\components\elements\modal\update-keyword-modal\update-keyword-modal.component.ts

I understand the error, but I struggle to how to fix :(

update-keyword-modal.component.ts depends on  unique-keyword-name-validator.ts

```js
import { UniqueKeywordNameValidator } from '../../validator/unique-keyword-name-validator';

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private fileUtils: FileUtils,
    private uniqueKeywordName: UniqueKeywordNameValidator,
    private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<UpdateKeywordModalComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) data) {
    this.name = data.keyword.name;
  }

      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.updateKeywordForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          keywordName: [this.name, [Validators.required], [this.uniqueKeywordName.keywordNameValidator(this.name)], ['blur']]
        });
      }
```

unique-keyword-name-validator.ts depends on  keyword.service.ts

```js
import { KeywordService } from "src/app/services/keyword/keyword.service";

  constructor(private keywordService: KeywordService) {}

       keywordNameValidator(oldname : string): AsyncValidatorFn {
          return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
            return this.keywordService.checkUniqueName(control.value).pipe(
              map(res => {
                if (oldname == control.value) {
                    res = false;
                }
                  // if res is true, keywordName exists, return true
                  return res ? { uniqueKeyword: true } : null;
                  // NB: Return null if there is no error
                
              })
            );
          };
        }
```

keyword.service.ts depends on  update-keyword-modal.component.ts

```js
import { UpdateKeywordModalComponent } from 'src/app/components/elements/modal/update-keyword-modal/update-keyword-modal.component';

      const modalDialog = this.matDialog.open(UpdateKeywordModalComponent, dialogConfig);
        return modalDialog.afterClosed();
```

Can you help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: Maybe what you could do you create a Interface for modals, eg. `ModalComponentInterface` and in your service you will relay on that interface instead single component. Then, your component `UpdateKeywordModalComponent` should implement that interface and pass in the component instance to the service, where you could use any component that can be shown in the modal (because that component implements your interface)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an angular specific issue, but more application design specific issue.

If two services are causing this, you could use `Injector` in constructor and call service via that, but since that's not an issue, you could try to keep the method for loading the `UpdateKeywordModalComponent` modal in another service or keep in the `unique-keyword-name-validator.ts`  and use it upon response from the `keyword.service.ts`.

This could help you avoid the issue.